# Removing very big peaks in a signal

Tags: noise, peak-detection, noise-cancellation

I am analyzing a signal where I want to extract the peaks based on a threshold. My problem here is that there are some noise artifacts very high that are messing with my signal. I want to remove them but I don't know which is the best way to do so.

Any suggestions or recommendations to avoid those peaks?

[image]

Comment: what about simply looking for values whose abs() > 500?

Comment: @Brethlosze not following you; the amplitude is exactly what makes spikes, no?

Comment: I want to remove the peaks above 300 microvolts (that's the amplitude units) which are the peaks in the circle.

Comment: Could you please add some information on their cause, how they differ from what you want to detect, and maybe show a zoom?

Comment: Well, I could remove them by 1) inspection of peaks, 2) inspection of isolated peaks (regions without many peaks, set arbitrarly) and 3) check the std. If the std is lower than the overall std, then I remove the peak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question lack some critical information so perhaps this answer is not definitive.

In the following, we asume a discrete time t with a sampling time dt.

**Cumulated Value**

Sometimes, what you need to measure is the cumulated value, approximated in discrete time this is just an integral. This is not a relevant method, but consider the expression for the following.
$$
x_f(t)=x_f(t-dt)+dtx(t)\\
x_f(t)\approx \int_0^t x(\tau) d\tau
$$

**Detect a Low Pass Magnitude**

You have a reason to go with a low pass filter. Note how you increased $dt$ into a greater but still small quantity $b<1$, with $b=(1-a)$. This simply impose a *forgetting factor* as we are having a first order filter.
$$
x_f(t)=ax_f(t-dt)+(1-a)x(t)\\
x_f(t)\approx \int_0^t x(\tau)e^{-at} d\tau
$$

**Detect a Windowed Magnitude**

If your peaks are due to outliers events, the Energy would be the best way to go, but the cumulative previous sense could be too much. In here, applying the Low Pass can help. Also, you can apply a window, if a time interval $T$ have some meaning for the process behind your application.
$$
x_f(t)=x_f(t-dt)+dtx(t)-dtx(t-T)\\
x_f(t)\approx \int_{t-T}^t x(\tau) d\tau
$$

**Detect Energy**

If the squared measured variable has a physical meaning, you can use it as filtered quantity to assess your detection. In some cases (voltage, current, pressure, sound, displacement, velocity), it is related to some form of energy. When using the squared variable, you are calculating a cumulative RMS with $t$ the window. Remember the RMS relates to the standard deviation $\sigma$ if your signal is normalized in mean.
$$
x_{f}(t)={t-dt \over t}x_{f}(t-dt)+ {dt \over t} x^2(t)\\
RMS^2_t\{x(t)\}=x_{f}(t)\approx \frac 1 t \int_0^t x^2(\tau) d\tau\\
\sigma^2={t \over t-dt} RMS^2_t\{x(t)\} \approx RMS^2_t\{x(t)\}
$$

**Other Magnitudes**

Finally, some combinations of the previous can be useful for applying a threshold on your auxiliary variable. Please add in the comments how your process works for the previous magnitudes.

$$
e(t)=[x_f(t)>x_0]
$$